# WM_QUERYENDSESSION does not fire when main form is minimized to the system tray

Tags: c#, windows, shutdown, system-tray, wndproc

I'm trying to catch WM_QUERYENDSESSION on system shutdown to clean some data in my app, but it looks like WM_QUERYENDSESSION fires up only when the main form is visible or minimized to the taskbar. When my app is minimized to the system tray WM_QUERYENDSESSION does not occur at all.

```
    private static int WM_QUERYENDSESSION = 0x11;
    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_QUERYENDSESSION)
        {
            systemShutdown = true;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);

    }

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        //WM_QUERYENDSESSION only fires when ShowInTaskbar = true
    }

    private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }
```

So the question is:
Is it even possible to catch WM_QUERYENDSESSION when my app is minimized to the system tray?